# xsl group not empty elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml :

```
<Row>

<one>1</one>
<two>2</two>
<tree>3</tree>
<four>4</four>
<five></five>
<six></six>
<seven></seven>

</Row>
```

Expected xml :

```
<tree>3</tree>
<four>4</four>
```

I want to ignore all elements and group by my condition .

My xsl is :

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::one or self::two)] and *[not(node())] "/>  
    </xsl:template>
```

But I get an Empty XML.

Comment: How is this grouping non-empty elements? Elements `one` and `two` also contain text, but do not appear in your expected output.

Comment: I want to get all the not empty elements and not one and two. so we left with tree and four

Answer (score 0):

If, I use your comment as your goal : "I want to get all the not empty elements and not one and two. so we left with tree and four", you'll need to fix your Xpath to achieve it.
"*[not(node())]" will exclude every node() with a node() as child, but node() select text nodes too, that's why you get nothing. If you want to filter out only elements with elements as child, use '*'.
So, this template for the Row should do the job (not tested) :

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::one or self::two) and not(* or text() ='')] "/>  
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What this line from your original code (I slightly changed it, since you cannot have the `]` appearing in the middle of the predicate):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::one or self::two) and not(node())] "/>
```

does is, in plain English:

> Apply templates to elements, but only if they are not `one` elements, or if they are not `two` elements, and only if they do not contain any child node.

But, of course, you'd like to select the exact opposite, that is, the elements that do contain text.

In my opinion, using different templates for this task would be a cleaner solution.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Traverse the Row element-->
  <xsl:template match="Row">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Do not apply templates to one, two or empty elements-->
  <xsl:template match="Row/*[self::one or self::two or not(text())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

Note that you are not outputting a well-formed XML document. But it would be a valid XML *fragment*.

```
<tree>3</tree>
<four>4</four>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a code that works finaly :

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(normalize-space()='') and not (self::one or self::two)] "/>  
    </xsl:template>
```

notice that `not(normalize-space()='')` should be at the start of the logic sentence.

this will result :

```
<tree>3</tree>
<four>4</four>
```

Comment: No, it does not matter if the condition covering textual content comes last. - And no, your code is invalid because there are two closing `]`.

Comment: You can try "*[ not (self::one or self::two)] and not(normalize-space()='')" putting the not empty in the end of the sentence and you will get an empty document.